# "unexpected others" in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, hdl

so I have a question to a vhdl error IT says: unexpected OTHER.

```
led <= "0000001" when count = "0000" else
        "1001111" when count = "0001" else
        "0010010" when count = "0010" else
        "0110000" when count = "0011" else
        "1001101" when count = "0100" else
        "0100101" when count = "0101" else
        "0100000" when count = "0110" else
        "0001111" when count = "0111" else
        "1111111" when count = "1000" else
        "0000100" when count = "1001" else
         "1111110" when others ;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write `others`. Do it like this:

```
led <= "0000001" when count = "0000" else
    "1001111" when count = "0001" else
    "0010010" when count = "0010" else
    "0110000" when count = "0011" else
    "1001101" when count = "0100" else
    "0100101" when count = "0101" else
    "0100000" when count = "0110" else
    "0001111" when count = "0111" else
    "1111111" when count = "1000" else
    "0000100" when count = "1001" else
     "1111110" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

A more standard way to do this would be.

```
with count select 
led <=  "0000001" when "0000",
        "1001111" when "0001",
        "0010010" when "0010",
        "0110000" when "0011",
        "1001101" when "0100",
        "0100101" when "0101",
        "0100000" when "0110",
        "0001111" when "0111",
        "1111111" when "1000",
        "0000100" when "1001",
        "1111110" when others;
```

And you have to use `others`. Because all the `count` values are not covered.